# How to execute setTimeout in order regardless of the timing using Promise?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently having this piece of code:

```
var timeOne = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('This is one');
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
}); 

var timeTwo = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('This is two');
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
}); 

    timeOne.then(timeTwo);
```

My desired out come is to display timeOne result before timeTwo regardless of what Math.random() provides. I'm currently struggling with this promise "thingy". Can anyone clarify why the code above isnt working as intended? (it still can display "This is two" before "This is one").

Comment: You never resolve your promises.

Comment: You're *immediately* creating two promises which *immediately* sets the two timeouts; the `then` is rather useless. You want to 1) `resolve` the first promise at some point and 2) in the callback function to `then` create a second timeout; the second promise is entirely superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var timeOne = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('This is one');
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
});

var timeTwo = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('This is two');
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
});

timeOne.then(function(m) {
  console.log(m);
  return timeTwo;
}).then(function(m) {
  console.log(m);
  return 'done';
}).then(function(m){
  console.log(m);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what everyone said in the comments. Here's how you could do it:

```js
var timeOne = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(console.log('This is one'));
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
  }); 
}

var timeTwo = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(console.log('This is two'));
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
  }); 
}

timeOne().then(timeTwo);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code seems to be working for me. However, may I ask why the last line isn't `timeOne().then(timeTwo())`, and when I do it, it doesn't display the correct order sometimes. Can you clarify this for me?

Comment: You need to pass a function to `.then()`, `timeTwo()` is not a function but the result of an executed function. So you can either do `.then(() => { timeTwo(); })` or `.then(timeTwo)`